# devexpress aspxListBox in detailsView validation

Tags: devexpress, asp.net-4.0

Is it possible to validate in insert or edit mode in detailsView AspxListBox control so that it has at least one value selected ?

code below doesnt work:

```
<requiredfieldvalidator ID="lbValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="lbMyListBox">
                    </requiredfieldvalidator>
```

thanks for any help,
bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:
`<dxe:ASPxListBox ID="liListBox" runat="server">
 <ValidationSettings CausesValidation="true" ErrorDisplayMode="Text">
  <RequiredField IsRequired="true" ErrorText="Required" />
 </ValidationSettings>
</dxe:ASPxListBox>`